# Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventGrid: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-functions, azure-function-app, azure-eventgrid

I have an azure function V3 (consumption plan, windows, .net 3.1), also using dependency injection.
The function was working fine, published many time before.
After the last publish, it was working fine and did too many requests.
suddenly I'm getting 503 error with "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventGrid: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Tried to restart the app service, republish the same code ... nothing resolve my issue.

Please advice.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, with the same code that was working until yesterday, and today it started breaking even without a code re-publish. It's really frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar symptoms, and for me it turned out that the latest update of EF Core was causing issues. I'm not sure why yet, but I reverted `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` back from 5.0.4 to 3.1.1 and everything started working again.